# Connected to the Internet using LAN but I'm unable to access websites using any browser (Chrome & Opera gx) but devices connected to Hotspot is

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, internet-connection

My laptop has been connected to the Internet using LAN but I'm unable to access websites using any browser (Chrome, Edge & Opera GX).

I'm able google but that's it. It won't load the site when I click the hyperlink.(youtube sometime works)

But when I turned on the mobile hotspot, the devices connected are able to use Internet freely but not the laptop, the one sharing it.

It says site can't be reached and connection was reset but no such problem occurred when accessing the same site using a different device.

Yes the LAN I'm connected to has some restrictions but just to be clear I used my friend's laptop to check if it was happening to his as well but no such problem occurred.

I have no clue what's going on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Win10? Win11? Have you ran the Internet Connection Troubleshooter?  For Windows 10, click to Start > Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot, and then select the troubleshooter for Internet Connections. Did you check proxy and dns settings?

Comment: What's the DNS server set to on the LAN adapter?

Comment: If W10, check Network Status > Properties, then try toggling Network profile (Public vs Private).  Optionally, check Random hardware addresses and Metered connection settings.  Also, if your mobile hotspot restricts the number and types of devices (by MAC) allowed to connect through it, then ensure to remove any previously registered devices that were simply used for testing (eg, your friend's laptop).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @spikey_richie's comment, if you can access the internet from the PC, e.g., ping outside the LAN, or go to a specific IP address (put 1.1.1.1 in the URL bar of your browser to view Clodflare's home page), then the issue is that the Domain Name Service (DNS) lookup (name resolution) is failing. When you type "https://brave.com/" in a URL bar, DNS looks up that name and translates into an IPv4 or IPv6 string to identify a particular server, and that is not working.

Depending on OS, e.g., [Windows](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10) or [Ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/set-dns-name-servers-ubuntu-linux/), open the dialog to set the DNS NameServer. If it's set to *automatic*, try changing to a specific NameServer, such as the aforementioned [1.1.1.1](https://1.1.1.1/), or, if it's already set to a specific server change it to *automatic*. Some Internet Service Providers (ISP's) may block a specific DNS provider; I've found public wireless access points that require DNS be through *their own* NameServer, so the automatic setting is needed there.